# Script executed from crontab is not running

Tags: mysql, cron

Good day all,

I have a Docker Container with Ubuntu OS and MySQL installed.

I need to restart the MySQL once a day and would normally use cron to do this.

When I run the script via the CLI the scripts runs perfectly within the Docker Container.

Script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Stopping MySQL" 
service mysql stop 
sleep 15s 
echo "Starting MySQL" 
service mysql start
sleep 10s 
echo "MySql Restarted" 
service mysql status 
sleep 10s
```

Log when running from CLI, using `./mysqlRestart >>/var/log/mysqlRestart 2>&1:`

```
Stopping MySQL

Stopping MySQL database server mysqld ...done. 
Starting MySQL
Starting MySQL database server mysqld su: warning: cannot change directory to /nonexistent: No such file or directory ...done. 
MySql Restarted
/usr/bin/mysqladmin Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)) Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Server version 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 Protocol version 10 Connection Localhost via UNIX socket UNIX socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock Uptime: 11 sec

Threads: 2 Questions: 8 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 119 Flush tables: 3 Open tables: 38 Queries per second avg: 0.727

crontab -e entry: */5 * * * * bash /usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart >>/var/log/mysqlRestart 2>&1
```

Log when running from crontab:

```
Stopping MySQL /usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart: line 4: service: command not found 
Starting MySQL /usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart: line 7: service: command not found 
MySql Restarted /usr/local/bin/mysqlRestart: line 10: service: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

The super user account that the cron job is running under does not know where to find `service`. You will need to use the full path to the command:

```
/usr/sbin/service mysql restart
```

You may want o double-check that run time, though, as every five minutes is a bit excessive. If your database needs to be restarted every day, that generally points to:

- inefficient SQL queries
- insufficient memory
- poor I/O performance

If it's at all possible, it may be worthwhile looking at optimising your Docker container settings to reduce the need for this sort of workaround

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the feedback I will test and revert

Comment: The 5 minute internal was purely for my testing.  It will be changed to a longer interval once I have the cronjib working. Thanks!